# AutoScroll Up to unblock TextField when keyboard shows up

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

In Swift, I am using a `UIViewController`. In that I have used a `UITableView` with 10 rows and 1 section. Every Rows contain `UITextField`. So how to auto-scroll the `tableView` when bottom cells editing start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
func keyboardWillShow(notification:NSNotification){
    var info:NSDictionary = notification.userInfo!
    var keyboardSize = (info[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).CGRectValue()

    var keyboardHeight:CGFloat =  keyboardSize.height - 40

    var animationDuration:CGFloat = info[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as! CGFloat

    var contentInsets: UIEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, keyboardHeight, 0.0);
    self.IBtableView.contentInset = contentInsets
    self.IBtableView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets
    //self.IBtableView.contentInset.bottom = keyboardHeight

}
func keyboardWillHide(notification:NSNotification){
    self.IBtableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero
    self.IBtableView.scrollIndicatorInsets = UIEdgeInsetsZero

}

override func viewDidDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self, name: UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
     NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self, name: UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
    println("Fired DidDisapper")
}

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("keyboardWillShow:"), name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("keyboardWillHide:"), name: UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
    println("Fired Appear")
}
```